# SQL Server unindo tabelas com null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
Responsavel             |     Filho
Id      Nome            |     Id    Nome           ResponsavelId
1       Ana             |     1     Aninha         1
2       Maria           |     2     Ana Júlia      1
3       Pedro           |     3     Mariazinha     2
```

Gostaria de fazer um `SELECT` com `INNER JOIN` onde apresentasse o seguinte resultado:

```
Id    Responsavel     Filho
1     Ana             Aninha
1     Ana             Ana Júlia
2     Maria           Mariazinha
3     Pedro           NULL
```

Preciso desse valor **nulo**. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Eu devo usar `Left Join`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa utilizar o `LEFT JOIN`, leia mais sobre [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join).

```
SELECT 
    Responsavel.Id
    Responsavel.Nome,
    Filho.Nome
FROM Responsavel
LEFT JOIN Filho
    ON Responsavel.Id = Filho.ResponsavelId
```